# Fill in between graphs in an animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying an animation of `w`  but i want to add a dynamic fill in between lines in order to simulate water waves but the fill isn't keeping up. I'm new to python and `w` is of a shape of (21,100) and `x` (1,100).

```
n = np.arange(0,np.shape(w)[0]) 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))      
ax  = plt.axes()
line, = ax.plot([], [],linewidth=2)  
plt.axis((0,10,0,4))             
plt.xlabel('Space x')
plt.ylabel('h(x,t)')


def plot_q(n):
    line.set_data(x,w[n])  
    plt.fill_between(x,w[n],facecolor='dodgerblue',alpha=0.5) 

anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plot_q, frames=n)  # Animate the solution

HTML(anim.to_jshtml())
```

Here is a data sample:

```
x=np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

w=np.asarray([[1.        , 1.02020202, 1.04040404, 1.06060606, 1.08080808,
       1.1010101 , 1.12121212, 1.14141414, 1.16161616, 1.18181818,
       1.2020202 , 1.22222222, 1.24242424, 1.26262626, 1.28282828,
       1.3030303 , 1.32323232, 1.34343434, 1.36363636, 1.38383838,
       1.4040404 , 1.42424242, 1.44444444, 1.46464646, 1.48484848,
       1.50505051, 1.52525253, 1.54545455, 1.56565657, 1.58585859,
       1.60606061, 1.62626263, 1.64646465, 1.66666667, 1.68686869,
       1.70707071, 1.72727273, 1.74747475, 1.76767677, 1.78787879,
       1.80808081, 1.82828283, 1.84848485, 1.86868687, 1.88888889,
       1.90909091, 1.92929293, 1.94949495, 1.96969697, 1.98989899,
       2.01010101, 2.03030303, 2.05050505, 2.07070707, 2.09090909,
       2.11111111, 2.13131313, 2.15151515, 2.17171717, 2.19191919,
       2.21212121, 2.23232323, 2.25252525, 2.27272727, 2.29292929,
       2.31313131, 2.33333333, 2.35353535, 2.37373737, 2.39393939,
       2.41414141, 2.43434343, 2.45454545, 2.47474747, 2.49494949,
       2.51515152, 2.53535354, 2.55555556, 2.57575758, 2.5959596 ,
       2.61616162, 2.63636364, 2.65656566, 2.67676768, 2.6969697 ,
       2.71717172, 2.73737374, 2.75757576, 2.77777778, 2.7979798 ,
       2.81818182, 2.83838384, 2.85858586, 2.87878788, 2.8989899 ,
       2.91919192, 2.93939394, 2.95959596, 2.97979798, 3.        ], 
        [1.06576968, 1.06448335, 1.06062011, 1.06481119, 1.08922855,
       1.102531  , 1.12720547, 1.14589292, 1.16660099, 1.1863154 ,
       1.2061828 , 1.22595996, 1.2457344 , 1.26549642, 1.285251  ,
       1.3049989 , 1.32474132, 1.34447934, 1.36421408, 1.38394667,
       1.40367825, 1.42341   , 1.44314308, 1.4628787 , 1.48261805,
       1.50236234, 1.5221128 , 1.54187063, 1.56163708, 1.58141335,
       1.60120066, 1.62100025, 1.64081331, 1.66064106, 1.68048471,
       1.70034557, 1.72022551, 1.74012867, 1.76006885, 1.7800884 ,
       1.80032783, 1.82110244, 1.84324254, 1.86778309, 1.89662654,
       1.92980098, 1.96610422, 2.00268649, 2.03676823, 2.06943523,
       2.09318444, 2.10629531, 2.11618768, 2.12374079, 2.13154344,
       2.14179085, 2.15540548, 2.17217701, 2.19052384, 2.20981605,
       2.22940281, 2.249099  , 2.26879698, 2.28847139, 2.30811242,
       2.32771832, 2.34728885, 2.36682431, 2.38632519, 2.40579203,
       2.42522547, 2.44462622, 2.46399503, 2.48333276, 2.5026403 ,
       2.52191863, 2.54116878, 2.56039185, 2.57958901, 2.5987615 ,
       2.61791065, 2.63703817, 2.65614722, 2.67524697, 2.69436945,
       2.71362172, 2.7333342 , 2.75434892, 2.7786413 , 2.80921384,
       2.85073978, 2.90099302, 2.95694744, 2.99098984, 3.00022759,
       2.9895901 , 2.9507802 , 2.96492329, 2.93787154, 2.96353132], 
        [1.17681003, 1.17454377, 1.17196604, 1.17019713, 1.16486845,
       1.16280674, 1.16136757, 1.17000475, 1.18398267, 1.19958266,
       1.21931503, 1.23709118, 1.25649033, 1.2748444 , 1.2935585 ,
       1.3120069 , 1.33049414, 1.34893037, 1.36736186, 1.38578332,
       1.40420334, 1.42262565, 1.44105503, 1.45949595, 1.47795291,
       1.49643046, 1.51493321, 1.5334661 , 1.55203509, 1.57064933,
       1.58932679, 1.60810785, 1.62708499, 1.64645528, 1.66660873,
       1.68820179, 1.71222199, 1.7397069 , 1.77141161, 1.80677045,
       1.84396275, 1.88047343, 1.91503036, 1.94891074, 1.98433107,
       2.02129594, 2.05878203, 2.09566103, 2.13246308, 2.16963256,
       2.19566503, 2.20930132, 2.2214615 , 2.23289671, 2.24400499,
       2.25602127, 2.26801525, 2.27821186, 2.28573779, 2.29206699,
       2.29919173, 2.30861177, 2.32073218, 2.33510081, 2.35097123,
       2.36770148, 2.38481329, 2.40205104, 2.41927008, 2.4364124 ,
       2.45345307, 2.47038841, 2.48722644, 2.50399343, 2.52075485,
       2.53766494, 2.55506197, 2.57362113, 2.59453644, 2.61958382,
       2.65074066, 2.6888404 , 2.73142439, 2.7708337 , 2.79672044,
       2.80087683, 2.78581101, 2.76078506, 2.739049  , 2.73070667,
       2.72704091, 2.73417962, 2.72708319, 2.72322591, 2.70818358,
       2.71070135, 2.69143846, 2.70277977, 2.67692698, 2.6991313 ], 
        [1.28293337, 1.27993277, 1.27533621, 1.27256042, 1.26840312,
       1.26854057, 1.26784131, 1.26596642, 1.26196762, 1.25871391,
       1.25922676, 1.26596062, 1.27643811, 1.29053086, 1.30618797,
       1.32236774, 1.33916463, 1.35565136, 1.37237863, 1.38890542,
       1.40551763, 1.42208982, 1.43872173, 1.45541901, 1.47226585,
       1.48938869, 1.50703179, 1.5256081 , 1.54575885, 1.56834419,
       1.59430159, 1.62425271, 1.65799935, 1.69411027, 1.7304102 ,
       1.76516448, 1.79845156, 1.83202283, 1.86750413, 1.90473346,
       1.94224258, 1.97889325, 2.01549286, 2.05314244, 2.09164021,
       2.12980198, 2.16798108, 2.20655701, 2.24556223, 2.28414938,
       2.31057334, 2.32452428, 2.33721481, 2.34917183, 2.36073203,
       2.37258185, 2.38345459, 2.39273354, 2.40099861, 2.40962871,
       2.41890773, 2.42775874, 2.43461919, 2.43902067, 2.44202173,
       2.44554604, 2.45142257, 2.46097728, 2.47513637, 2.49471102,
       2.52028546, 2.55144093, 2.58549634, 2.61675695, 2.63774597,
       2.64269211, 2.63111457, 2.60840119, 2.5831717 , 2.56301045,
       2.55209386, 2.54953602, 2.5508174 , 2.5507693 , 2.54424073,
       2.53467778, 2.52159304, 2.51307885, 2.50569251, 2.5023855 ,
       2.49398227, 2.490606  , 2.4787547 , 2.47627918, 2.46339446,
       2.4664185 , 2.44855265, 2.45682455, 2.4323834 , 2.45113663], 
        [1.38249079, 1.37872793, 1.373394  , 1.37009395, 1.36589604,
       1.36342711, 1.35906977, 1.35496694, 1.35212315, 1.35180642,
       1.3511113 , 1.34884476, 1.34462025, 1.34132823, 1.34145328,
       1.34589497, 1.35424787, 1.36568861, 1.37905072, 1.39407095,
       1.41054717, 1.42890579, 1.44988946, 1.47424103, 1.50260673,
       1.53473439, 1.56940425, 1.60450346, 1.63824488, 1.67030766,
       1.70213227, 1.73557787, 1.77119597, 1.80778346, 1.84381521,
       1.87912971, 1.91492108, 1.95186508, 1.98940139, 2.02666118,
       2.0637562 , 2.10122252, 2.13927204, 2.17727941, 2.2151329 ,
       2.25302429, 2.29135849, 2.32949978, 2.36754068, 2.40539377,
       2.43064285, 2.4425132 , 2.45302552, 2.46335351, 2.47350997,
       2.4839095 , 2.49422641, 2.50545328, 2.51925282, 2.5370396 ,
       2.55846879, 2.58160579, 2.60326947, 2.61924529, 2.62474374,
       2.61620671, 2.59346818, 2.56050599, 2.52398701, 2.49065681,
       2.46510326, 2.4486745 , 2.43958646, 2.43391452, 2.42747351,
       2.4175928 , 2.40430521, 2.38987011, 2.37674045, 2.36705314,
       2.35943703, 2.35336891, 2.3456474 , 2.33697149, 2.32665067,
       2.31796979, 2.30840012, 2.30202881, 2.29319986, 2.28716774,
       2.27686784, 2.27264963, 2.26152151, 2.25912929, 2.2460255 ,
       2.24776017, 2.2311783 , 2.23801278, 2.21544226, 2.23131764]])
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Mr.T it's not giving errors it's giving a wrong animation, i'll upload right now pics

Comment: @Mr.T I'm sorry, my bad, i rushed my explanations. I uploaded pics to understand better my problem. "It isn't working" == the fill in between lines isn't keeping up with the animation as shown on my pics.

Comment: @Mr.T  I just need to know is there's a way the blue fill in between could be updated ? Look at the last pic the fill must be underneath the black line...

Comment: Ah, so the wave effect with different shades of blue is not intended but a residue of previous fills? I thought that WAS the wave effect you were trying to generate.

Comment: @Mr.T the shades is only because i added on `plt.fill_between(x,w[n],facecolor='dodgerblue',alpha=0.5)` , alpha=0.5...it's a residue from previous fill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just clear the axis object before plotting the next step. You also have to make sure then that the scaling does not change between animation steps.

```
def plot_q(n):
    ax.cla()
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1.1 * w.max())
    ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
    line, = ax.plot(x,w[n], "k")  #Draw the next line at time t
    ax.fill_between(x,w[n],facecolor='dodgerblue',alpha=0.5)
```

Sample output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Furthermore, although the parameter `frames` accepts an iterable like `np.arange()`, you could also simply provide an integer value (which probably will be converted internally into a range): `n = w.shape[0]`